# Correct way to represent documents containing multiple sentences in gensim file-based training

Tags: gensim, corpus, doc2vec, sentence

I am trying to use gensim's file-based training (example from documentation below):

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from gensim.utils import save_as_line_sentence
from gensim.test.utils import get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, Doc2Vec, FastText
 # Convert any corpus to the needed format: 1 document per line, words delimited by " "
corpus = api.load("text8")
corpus_fname = get_tmpfile("text8-file-sentence.txt")
save_as_line_sentence(corpus, corpus_fname)
 # Choose num of cores that you want to use (let's use all, models scale linearly now!)
num_cores = cpu_count()
 # Train models using all cores
w2v_model = Word2Vec(corpus_file=corpus_fname, workers=num_cores)
d2v_model = Doc2Vec(corpus_file=corpus_fname, workers=num_cores)
ft_model = FastText(corpus_file=corpus_fname, workers=num_cores)
```

However, my actual corpus contains many documents, each containing many sentences.
For example, let's assume my corpus is the plays of Shakespeare - Each play is a document, each document has many many sentences, and I would like to learn embeddings for each play, but the word embeddings only from within the same sentence.
Since the file-based training is meant to be one document per line, I assume that I should put one play per line. However, the documentation for file-based-training doesn't have an example of any documents with multiple sentences.
Is there a way to peek inside the model to see the documents and word context pairs that have been found before they are trained?

What is the correct way to build this file, maintaining sentence boundaries?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These algorithm implementations don't have any real understanding of, or dependence on, actual sentences. They just take texts – runs of word-tokens.

Often the texts provided to `Word2Vec` will be multiple sentences. Sometimes punctuation like sentence-ending periods are even retained as pseudo-words. (And when the sentences were really consecutive with each other in the source data, the overlapping word-context windows, between sentences, may even be a benefit.)

So you don't have to worry about "maintaining sentence boundaries". Any texts you provide that are sensible units of words that really co-occur will work about as well. (Especially in `Word2Vec` and `FastText`, even changing your breaks between texts to be sentences, or paragraphs, or sections, or documents is unlikely to have very much effect on the final word-vectors – it's just changing a subset of the training contexts, and probably not in any way that significantly changes which words influence which other words.)

There is, however, another implementation limit in `gensim` that you should watch out for: each training text can only be 10,000 tokens long, and if you supply larger texts, the extra tokens will be silently ignored.

So, be sure to use texts that are 10k tokens or shorter – even if you have to arbitrarily split longer ones. (Per above, any such arbitrary extra break in the token grouping is unlikely to have a noticeable effect on results.)

However, this presents a special problem using `Doc2Vec` in `corpus_file` mode, because in that mode, you don't get to specify your preferred `tags` for a text. (A text's tag, in this mode, is essentially just the line-number.)

In the original sequence corpus mode, the workaround for this 10k token limit was just to break up larger docs into multiple docs - but use the same repeated `tags` for all sub-documents from an original document. (This very closely approximates how a doc of any size would affect training.)

If you have documents with more than 10k tokens, I'd recommend either not using `corpus_file` mode, or figuring some way to use logical sub-documents of less than 10k tokens, then perhaps modeling your larger docs as the set of their sub-documents, or otherwise adjusting your downstream tasks to work on the same sub-document units.